# ENVI 5: High resolution export of multiband imagery

Tags: raster, export, envi, landsat, resolution

I have to export some multiband Landsat imagery (Landsat channel combination 543) in high resolution in ENVI 5 for a Figure which I later will edit in Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator, best would be TIFF (geoinformation is not important).

My attempts to do this:

- I stacked all channels into one file with LayerStacking and then loaded the needed band combinations into a new view. However when I am trying to save that file, I can only select the stacked file with all bands.
- I know that there is the `Chip View to File` option but the output
  resolution is relatively low.

Is there a way to export it in higher resolution or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, If  i got you you mean visual enhancement. There are several way to enhance an image visually. I would suggest a simple one- band combination.
**Change the RGB order to get better visuals
**Export as Tiff(Use Save As in File Menu) as below
[image: ENVI]

N.B.
This may done Chipping too both are same.
Tiff is better comparing other format.
The main thing is RGB composite.